# UIActionSheet, cancel button runs method

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, uiactionsheet

Every time I press a cancel button in UIActionSheet, it runs a method. I have no idea why, I checked whole my code many times, but I still can't see the problem. Could you help me to find it ?

```
-(IBAction)moreOptions
{

    giftTitle = self.title;

     if(![giftTitle isEqualToString:@"bla"])
     {
        actionSheet = [[UIActionSheet alloc]initWithTitle:giftTitle
                                                            delegate:self
                                                   cancelButtonTitle:@"Back"
                                              destructiveButtonTitle:nil
                                                   otherButtonTitles:@"Send via email",
                                  @"Read in Wikipedia"
                                  , nil];
     }
    else 
    {
        actionSheet = [[UIActionSheet alloc]initWithTitle:giftTitle
                                                 delegate:self
                                        cancelButtonTitle:@"Back"
                                   destructiveButtonTitle:nil
                                        otherButtonTitles:@"Send via email",
                       @"Read in Wikipedia", @"Pineapple mode"
                       , nil];

    }
    actionSheet.actionSheetStyle = UIActionSheetStyleDefault;
    [actionSheet showInView:self.view.window];

}

- (void)actionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)actionSheet clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{

    // выстраеваем дальнейшие действия кнопок

        switch (buttonIndex) 
        {
            case 0:
                [self showPicker];
            break;

            case 1:
                [self goWiki];
            break;

            case 2:
                [self showPineapple];
            break;

            default:
            break;

        }

}
```

So it runs method `showPineapple`. Please help !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to implement something like this:

Change your `if` and `else` sections to add a unique tag for each UIActionSheet:

```
if(![giftTitle isEqualToString:@"bla"]) {
    actionSheet = [[UIActionSheet alloc]initWithTitle:giftTitle
                                             delegate:self
                                    cancelButtonTitle:@"Back"
                               destructiveButtonTitle:nil
                                    otherButtonTitles:@"Send via email", @"Read in Wikipedia" , nil];
    actionSheet.tag = 10;
} else {
    actionSheet = [[UIActionSheet alloc]initWithTitle:giftTitle
                                             delegate:self
                                    cancelButtonTitle:@"Back"
                               destructiveButtonTitle:nil
                                    otherButtonTitles:@"Send via email", @"Read in Wikipedia", @"Pineapple mode", nil];

    actionSheet.tag = 20;
}
```

Then look for the tag in the actionSheet:clickedButtonAtIndex: message handler:

```
case 2:
   if (actionSheet.tag == 20)
      [self showPineapple];
   break;
```

This means `[self showPineapple]` will only run in the `else` scenario, while nothing will happen in the `if` scenario (just as nothing will happen for `buttonIndex` 3 in the `else` scenario (where the Cancel button is indeed at index 3) .

Comment: yeah, it worked ! Thank you !
Interesting, I have never heard about tag property.

Answer (score 1):

Ya when you press cancel button on action sheet then it's delegate function always call, with the last index.

If you are implementing multiple actionsheet then just use it by tag value.

Comment: Thanks !
So should I add case 3 with nothing inside then ?

Comment: You can place @"Send via email" at the place of destructiveButtonTitle

Comment: hmm ... i wil wait for your response, and chk my answer i updated it.,.:)

Comment: Ok, I tried destructive button, but it makes @"Send via email" on red button, and I want it just on a simple button, so it will be logical and user friendly :) 
And I have no idea why, but when I press cancelButton, its still launches a function.
I don't really know about tags, could you explain please ?
Sorry for confusing.

Comment: Thank you @Rajhneesh071 !
Wildaker already explained me how it works.

Comment: then what i said to you....i was clearly mention in my answer to apply tag....just read my answer once..: